# How to query data with sequence of duplicated rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following table with data:

```
    ID  SAL         
_______________
    1   1500        
    1   1500        
    1   2000        
    1   1500        
    2   2500        
    2   2500        
    3   1500
```

I want to query the same data **BUT** with new column that gives me a sequence of each duplicated row (based on id and sal columns).

My desired query results should be like this:

```
   ID  SAL      ROW_SEQ
_______________________
    1   1500     1
    1   1500     2
    1   2000     1
    1   1500     3
    2   2500     1
    2   2500     2
    3   1500     1
```

Any one has any idea **PLEASE!..**

Comment: Row_Number() over (Partition By ID,Sal Order By Sal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a ROW_NUMBER() function here.

```
SELECT ID, SAL, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, SAL, ORDER BY SAL) AS ROW_SEQ
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY ID, SAL
```

By partitioning over your two desired fields, it will give you a ranking within each group in a sequential manner.

The documentation on it can be found here: 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm

Comment: thank you so much for your useful help, but the result of row_seq column returns result 1 for all rows.

Comment: Oops... replace `RANK()` with `ROW_NUMBER()` instead. Answer updated.